# Unable to query MongoDB document for specific information with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to the MEAN Stack, and just completed this tutorial : http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/learn-mean-stack-tutorial/

I have two mongoDB schemas setup with Mongoose - users and invoices. One has a field country and the other has a field firm, both of which contain a string, that is the name of the country. All users that make the accounts have different firms(countries). Aim is that the invoices displayed should only be for the firm(country) the user belongs to. So if the user is from Australia, he should only see invoices that are sent to Australia.
The problem is they are part of two different schemas. Here is the Invoices Schema :

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    validation = require('./validation.server.model');

/**
 * Invoices Schema
 */
var InvoiceSchema = new Schema({
    invoice_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    from_entity: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        /*required: 'service line cannot be blank'*/
    },
    from_service: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,     
        /*required: 'service line cannot be blank'*/
    },

    country: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        /*required: 'service line cannot be blank'*/
    },

    to_entity: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        /*required: 'service line cannot be blank'*/
    },

    to_service: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,     
        /*required: 'service line cannot be blank'*/

    },

    partner: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true  
        /*required: 'partner cannot be blank'*/
    },

    invoice_number: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,     
        unique: true
    },

    currency: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        /*required: 'currency cannot be blank'*/
    },


    amount: {
        type: Number,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        /*required: 'amount cannot be blank'*/
    }, 

    user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
});

mongoose.model('Invoice', InvoiceSchema);
```

Here is the User Schema :

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    crypto = require('crypto');

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy properties
 */
var validateLocalStrategyProperty = function(property) {
    return ((this.provider !== 'local' && !this.updated) || property.length);
};

/**
 * A Validation function for local strategy password
 */
var validateLocalStrategyPassword = function(password) {
    return (this.provider !== 'local' || (password && password.length > 6));
};

/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: 'testing error message',
        required: 'Please fill in a username',
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyPassword, 'Password should be longer']
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerData: {},
    additionalProvidersData: {},
    roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['Canada', 'Australia']
        }],
        default: ['Canada']
    },
    updated: {
        type: Date
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    /* For reset password */
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date
    },
    firm: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: 'Canada'
    }
});

/**
 * Hook a pre save method to hash the password
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});

/**
 * Create instance method for hashing a password
 */
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
    if (this.salt && password) {
        return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
    } else {
        return password;
    }
};

/**
 * Create instance method for authenticating user
 */
UserSchema.methods.authenticate = function(password) {
    return this.password === this.hashPassword(password);
};

/**
 * Find possible not used username
 */
UserSchema.statics.findUniqueUsername = function(username, suffix, callback) {
    var _this = this;
    var possibleUsername = username + (suffix || '');

    _this.findOne({
        username: possibleUsername
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (!err) {
            if (!user) {
                callback(possibleUsername);
            } else {
                return _this.findUniqueUsername(username, (suffix || 0) + 1, callback);
            }
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
    });
};

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Here is my invoices.server.controller :

```
        'use strict';

        /**
         * Module dependencies.
         */
        var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
          errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
          User = mongoose.model('User'),
          Invoice = mongoose.model('Invoice'),
            _ = require('lodash');

        var crud = require('./crud.server.controller')('Invoice', 'invoice_number');

        module.exports = crud;

    Here is my invoice.client.controller:

'use strict';

// Invoices controller
angular.module('invoices').controller('InvoicesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Invoices', 'Users', '$filter',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Invoices, Users, $filter) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
        $scope.users = Users.query();
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.pageSize = 10;
        $scope.offset = 0;

        // Page changed handler
        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
            $scope.offset = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.pageSize;
        };

        // Create new Invoice
        $scope.create = function() {
            var invoice = new Invoices ({
                    amount: this.amount,
                    invoice_number: this.invoice_number,
                    partner: this.partner,
                    to_service: this.to_service,
                    to_entity: this.to_entity,
                    country: this.country,
                    from_service: this.from_service,
                    from_entity: this.from_entity
            });

            // Redirect after save
            invoice.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('invoices/' + response._id);

                // Clear form fields
                $scope.name = '';
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

        // Remove existing Invoice
        $scope.remove = function(invoice) {
            if (invoice) {
                invoice.$remove();

                for (var i in $scope.invoices) {
                    if ($scope.invoices [i] === invoice) {
                        $scope.invoices.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $scope.invoice.$remove(function() {
                    $location.path('invoices');
                });
            }
        };

        // Update existing Invoice
        $scope.update = function() {
            var invoice = $scope.invoice;

            invoice.$update(function() {
                $location.path('invoices/' + invoice._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

// MY CODE
        var findInvoice = function findInvoice(p) {
            // You could substitue use of filter here with underscore etc.
            p.user = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {firm : Invoices.country});
        };

        // Find a list of Invoices
        $scope.find = function() {
                    $scope.invoices = Invoices.query(function countryInvoices (invoices) {
                    invoices.forEach(findInvoice);
                    $scope.invoices = invoices;
                });
            };


        // Find existing Invoice
        $scope.findOne = function() {
            $scope.invoice = Invoices.get({ 
                invoiceId: $stateParams.invoiceId
            });
        };


        // Search for a Invoice
        $scope.invoiceSearch = function(invoice) {
            $location.path('invoices/' + invoice._id);
        };
    }
]);
```

As you can see the image below, the China shows up there but it is not supposed to because the user is logged in from Canada.

[image]

Help would be appreciated. Please let me know if troubleshooting requires posting more code.

Answer (score 0):

You would send a request that somehow includes the country portion of your user object.

It ends up looking something like this:

In the controller:

```
$scope.user = Auth.getCurentUser();

invoiceAPI.getUserInvoices($scope.user.country)
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.userInvoices = data;
  });
```

The Service for this is:

```
function getUserInvoices(id) {
  var url = '/api/invoice/?country=' + id;
  var request = $http.get(url, {
    cache: true
  });
  return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

And the server controller is:

```
 exports.userInvoices = function(req, res) {
  Invoice.find({
    country: {
      $in: req.query.country
    }
  })
  .exec(function(err, looks) {
    if (err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    console.log(looks);
    return res.status(200)
      .json(looks);
  });
};
```

Comment: The firm field would be a user requirement upon sign up. How would I use $in to find the data I need ? Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer.  I think this would work but its a little harder if your not referencing one schema with another somewhere in the model.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to explain whats going on... I am unable to understand. Since I am new to MEAN, I am unsure if this is the code I should be 'copy-pasting' or if it just pseudo-code meant to explain.

Comment: Its mostly pseudo-code.  I'm not a fan of the structure of the author's code so not trying to dig through it.  There's some better - get you running tutorials on scotch.io.  For example, authentication is something that should be taught on its own.